# Improving draw/scroll/animate performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiview, calayer

**The problem**

I have a view in my app. An example of which might look like this...

[image]

At the moment I have it just as a `UIView` with multiple `UIImageViews` in it. But there are multiple of these on the screen at one time.

However, as I expected (and knew about it but wanted to get it working ASAP), the performance is poo. I'm getting around 40FPS on a iPhone 4S.

I'm trying to think of different ways to display the view so that the draw/animate performance isn't so bad.

**A couple of things to note**

1. At the moment the view is transparent and each image has transparency (images have to have transparency for use elsewhere). However, in the non-editable version the view is always displayed on a white background.
2. There are some images that may take a while to deliver as they come down from the internet.
3. All the images are displayed at exactly the same size.

**Things I've thought of**

***Keep it as it is.***

This is the easiest thing to do but would give really poor performance on some devices when there are lots of views on the screen.

***Draw Rect***

I could render each image directly into the view with a white background. Using CoreGraphics to render everything. However, I'm not sure this would be as effective as I believe as I thin it would get called more often that I expect??

***CALayers***

This is what I'm thinking is probably the best option but I'm just not sure how best to do this. If I can create a CALayer with the images laid out as the contents and then just display it. I'm thinking this would be the best option but not sure how best to go about it.

***Render to UIImage***

I could render the whole view to a single UIImage with a white background and then just display that as a single view.

**Question**

I'm on my own here and trying to get some input from people with knowledge around this area so looking for advice on how best to start trying to improve the performance of this part of the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these and you have to render them at realtime speeds, you may want to look into using OpenGL-ES for that.

You may implement OpenGL-ES yourself with `GLKView` or use an existing solution such as Cocos2d-iPhone.

Comment: Thanks. They are in a table view and so there will be maybe 7 or 8 on screen at any one time. Is that enough to warrant going down this route?

Comment: No. I thought you meant you had hundreds of these on screen. 7 or 8 shouldn't impact performance at all, maybe you should describe exactly what you're doing.

Comment: The problem is the transparency I think. I've dealt with performance issues before when I had 5 or 6 `UIImageViews` in a table but I was adding (layer.cornerRadius) to mask them into a circle. It has a much bigger effect than you would think.

Comment: I've never had a problem with that, and I have an app that consistently displays hundreds if not thousands of UITableViewCells with masked circles (profile pictures), maybe you should post the relevant parts of your code, because i've never ever had a problem with transparency being a bottleneck on iOS.

Comment: Well, you will never be displaying thousands of table view cells. You might be displaying 8 or 9 at one time. i.e. there are only ever 8 or 9 cells (dequeueing). Anyway, it is an issue, as told many times in various WWDC videos.

Comment: Just sounds weird that you'd have such an issue when other people (including me) are using way more images than you and not seeing a problem.

Comment: My suggestion is to use OpenGL-ES once you have too many images that you're completely SURE that rendering has become a bottleneck.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll have a look at it if it comes to that.

Comment: The downsides of using OpenGL-ES is that you won't be able to use UIKit anymore, but if you use a framework like Cocos2d you can use their CCButton, CCLabel, etc.

Comment: Transparency is only especially slow on iPhone 4 and earlier; it is merely slightly slower on the 4S and up. Still a good idea to make the views opaque if you don't need the transparency—particularly in table view cells and collection view cells—but it's not usually the biggest hit in performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the image views for display—then use layers. I recommend creating a single UIView subclass to manage a single set of layers, one layer for each image. Don't try to do the layer rendering yourself unless you really need it for functionality, as it's unlikely to be meaningfully faster.

If you're using auto layout for the image views, this might be a significant contributor to your performance problem—auto layout is a little slow when you're scrolling rapidly and many new views are laid out in many new cells every frame, especially on older devices. If you see ISIS* classes taking up a lot of time when you profile with instruments, that's auto layout.

Finally, make sure your networking is happening on a background thread to prevent it interrupting the UI and causing stutter.

Comment: Thanks  I'll take a look and let you know.